# Using ShouldSkipRecord to filter date ranges in CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

What would filtering date ranges look like using ShouldSkipRecord in csvhelper?

Googled a bunch but there is just a reference to its a callback and that not enough for me to pickup on what the syntax of ShouldSkipRecord call should look like. Do you pick it up by the columns and the rows. There is one short line in the API and thats it.

```
if (File.Exists(lastPathName))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(lastPathName))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<QuotedataMap>();
                    csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0] >= DateTime.Parse("12/12/2019");
                    var records =  csv.GetRecords<Quotedata>();
                    return records;
                }
            }


public sealed class QuotedataMap : ClassMap<Quotedata>
    {
        public QuotedataMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.QuoteDate).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.OpenPrice).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.HighPrice).Index(2);
            Map(m => m.LowPrice).Index(3);
            Map(m => m.ClosePrice).Index(4);
            Map(m => m.DateVolume).Index(5);
        }
    }
```

So how to you filter date ranges? >= <= == ?

Answer (score 4):

The row variable is a array of strings. So you have to convert the String to DateTime before comparing it.

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => DateTime.Parse(row[0]) >= DateTime.Parse("12/12/2019");
```

If your expression is going to be more complex, you could move it to a separate method.

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => FilterDataRange(row[0]);
```

The method than would look like this

```
private bool FilterDataRange(string quoteDateAsString)
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse(quoteDateAsString);
    return date >= new DateTime(2019, 12, 1) && date <= new DateTime(2019, 12, 31);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a beautiful example and I hope its added to the documentation!