# CSV file Blank field error with CSVHelper C#

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I've a problem to read this file with CSVHelper for example, how can I use a ShouldSkipRecord to not receive a exception? I've tried to keep all my Map columns Optional but doesn't work.

[PrintScreen Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh39h.jpg)

Class:

```
public class WheelProsAccessoriesInventoryItem : WheelProsBaseInventoryItem
   {
       public override string PartNumber { get; set; }
       public override string PartDescription { get; set; } 
       public override string Brand { get; set; } 
       public string CapHardwareDescription { get; set; } 
       public string CapScrewQuantity { get; set; } 
       public string CapWrench { get; set; } 
       public string CapStyleDescription { get; set; } 
       public string ImageURL { get; set; } 
       public override string TotalQOH { get; set; } 
       public override string Msrp { get; set; } 
       public override string Map { get; set; } 
       public override string RunDate { get; set; } 
       public override string StockLa1 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1015 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1019 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1022 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1028 { get; set; } 
       public override string StockLa2 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1036 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1071 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1072 { get; set; } 
       public override string num1082 { get; set; }  
       public override string StockLa3 { get; set; } 
       public override string StockTX { get; set; } 
       public override string num1092 { get; set; } 
       public override string StockLangley { get; set; } 
       public override string StockToronto { get; set; } 
       public int LineNumber { get; set; }
   }

}
```

MAP:

```
public class WheelProsAccessoriesInventoryItemMap : ClassMap<WheelProsAccessoriesInventoryItem>
    {**

        public WheelProsAccessoriesInventoryItemMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.PartNumber).Name("PartNumber");
            Map(m => m.Brand).Name("Brand");
            Map(m => m.PartDescription).Name("PartDescription");


            Map(m => m.CapHardwareDescription).Name("CapHardwareDescription").Optional();
            Map(m => m.CapScrewQuantity).Name("CapScrewQuantity").Optional();
            Map(m => m.CapWrench).Name("CapWrench").Optional();
            Map(m => m.CapStyleDescription).Name("CapStyleDescription").Optional();

            Map(m => m.ImageURL).Name("ImageURL");
  
            Map(m => m.TotalQOH).Name("TotalQOH");
            Map(m => m.Msrp).Name("MSRP");
            Map(m => m.Map).Name("MAP");
            Map(m => m.RunDate).Name("RunDate"); 

            // StockWarehouses

            // 1011 – Stock LA1 Warehouse
            Map(m => m.StockLa1).Name("1011");

            // 1031 - Stock LA2 Riverside
            Map(m => m.StockLa2).Name("1031");

            // 1085 – Stock LA3 LA Warehouse Support
            Map(m => m.StockLa3).Name("1085");

            // 1086 - StockTX Dallas Warehouse
            Map(m => m.StockTX).Name("1086");

            // 4033 - Stock Langley/Vancouver
            Map(m => m.StockLangley).Name("4033");

            // 4035 - Stock Toronto
            Map(m => m.StockToronto).Name("4035");

            // 1088 - Stock US - Atlanta Logistics Center
            Map(m => m.num1088).Name("1088"); 

            Map(m => m.num1015).Name("1015").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1019).Name("1019").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1022).Name("1022").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1028).Name("1028").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1036).Name("1036").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1071).Name("1071").Optional();
            Map(m => m.num1072).Name("1072").Optional();

            // Map(m => m.LineNumber).Convert(record => record.Row.Parser.Row);

        }

    }
}
```

Read Method:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T, TMap>(string filename, bool hasFrenchChars = false)
    where T : class
    where TMap : ClassMap<T>
    {
        var errorRecsCollection = new List<string>();
        var malformedRow = false;

       

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {

                    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();


                    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ",",
                        HasHeaderRecord = true,
                        Encoding = hasFrenchChars ? Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") : Encoding.UTF8,
                        IgnoreBlankLines = true,
              
                        MissingFieldFound = null,
                        
                        BadDataFound = context =>
                        {
                            malformedRow = true;

                            errorRecsCollection.Add(context.RawRecord);

                        }

                    };

                  //  var rowNumber = csvReader.Parser.Row;
                return csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();


                }

            }
       
         
    }
```

How I need to do to ignore the files? I've tried to add this config below but doesn't works.

Comment: Please put your error info directly in the question as text, not an image.

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: The image is not an error, the image is my read file. the error is: Field at index '17' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null.\r\nIReader state:\r\n   ColumnCount: 0\r\n   CurrentIndex: 17\r\n   HeaderRecord:\r\n[\"PartNumber\",\"PartDescription\",\"Brand\",\"CapHardwareDescription\",\"CapScrewQuantity\",\"CapWrench\",\"CapStyleDescription\",\"ImageURL\",\"TotalQOH\",\"MSRP\",\"MAP\",\"RunDate\",\"1011\",\"1015\",\"1019\",\"1022\",\"1028\",\"1031\",\"1036\",\........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle bad records (all code in the same method)

```
var isRecordBad = false;
csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
{
    isRecordBad = true;
    bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
};

var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>(); //You can still use your type and map, dynamic is sometimes just easier for complicated mappings

foreach (var record in records)
{
    var dictionary = record as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (!isRecordBad)
    {
        //keep the data - add to list
    }
    isRecordBad = false;
}
```

If you decide to go the `dynamic` type route you can also write less code and just check for the keys in the converted `dictionary` when generating the `WheelProsAccessoriesInventoryItem` object

Comment: the interesting thing is I don't receive nothing in my BadDataFound configuration. I Need to keep map and not use dynamic, I need to use ShouldSkipRecords but I Don't know how can I use it. for example one solution is counting the mapped headers and the data in rows with have less data skip the row record but I don't know how can I do this too ..

Comment: @LucasDJ Check this answer for an example of using ShouldSkipRecord https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444524/using-shouldskiprecord-to-filter-date-ranges-in-csvhelper

Comment: thank you!! you and Josh are very helpful .
I don't understand why I've a exception because I'm using the MissingFieldFound = null in my configuration.

Comment: You never added the exception details and stack trace to the question which might help if you're still getting the error.  If this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it as the answer by selecting the big check box to the left.

Comment: Thanks.. I've add the exception in first comment: MissingFieldFound to null.\r\nIReader state:\r\n ColumnCount: 0\r\n CurrentIndex: 17\r\n HeaderRecord:\r\n[\"PartNumber\",\"PartDescription\",\"Brand\",\"CapHardwareDescription\",\"CapScrewQuantity\",\"CapWrench\",\"CapStyleDescription\",\"ImageURL\",\"TotalQOH\",\"MSRP\",\"MAP\",\"RunDate\",\"1011\",\"1015\",\"1019\",\"1022\",\"1028\",\"1031\",\"1036\",\........

Comment: but I talk with Josh and I've two ways to solve this issue, one it's read manually because I don't have control with .csv and sometimes I receive bad data and other is using ShouldSkipRecord.
Thank you!